# Making simple calculator in C

Tags: c

I'm making a simple calculator in C with operators +-*/. I tried to make a calculator but I have some problem with using `do..while`. I think `while (op != 'A', 'Q', 'M', 'D', 'S');` is incorrect. What should I require here?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x, y, result;
    char op;

    printf("****************\n");
    printf("A-----Add\n");
    printf("S-----Substract\n");
    printf("M-----MUltiply\n");
    printf("D-----Divide\n");
    printf("Q-----Quit\n");
    printf("****************\n");

    printf("Enter the operation:");
    scanf("%c", &op);
    printf("Enter the two variables:");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    do {

        if (op == 'A')
            result = x + y;
        else if (op == 'S')
            result = x - y;
        else if (op == 'M')
            result = x*y;
        else if (op == 'D')
            result = x / y;
        else if (op == 'Q')
            break;
    } while (op != 'A', 'Q', 'M', 'D', 'S');

    printf("%d %c %d = %d\n", x, op, x, result);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are right. Here: } while (op != 'A' && op != 'Q' && op != 'M' && op != 'D' && op != 'S');

Comment: Furthermore, you probably want to have your scanf's in while block.

Comment: If code puts `scanf("%c", &op);` in the while loop, use `scanf(" %c", &op);`  (Add space)

Comment: ... otherwise it's an infinite loop!

Comment: You could try while (op != 'A'&& 'Q'&& 'M'&& 'D'&& 'S');, but what if the user type **a** instead of **A** ?

Comment: and what if the user types D)ivide with second operand `y == 0`?

Answer (score 1):

`!=` is a binary operator, it takes one value on the left and one value on the right. You can't compare multiple values at once by just listing several values on the right.

To get this code working with minimal changes, you can compare `op` to *each* the variables individually, and combine them using the standard logical operators (e.g. `&&`).

You also need to think about the logic of your code. You're using a `do ... while` loop, which means that code will run at least once, and each time it reaches the end it will run again if the `while` condition is true. What happens after its first run? What happens if the user input (`op`) is none of the options specified? And you've got a 'quit' option, but what happens when it's used?

Answer (score 0):

Four issues:

- This: `while (op != 'A', 'Q', 'M', 'D', 'S')` doesn't do what you expect.  You need to compare `op` against each value individually and do a logical AND (`&&`) between them.
- If you don't enter a proper letter, your `while` loop will be an infinite loop because the prompt for user data is outside of the loop instead of inside.  Move the `printf` and `scanf` calls to the inside of the loop.
- If you do get an invalid input, the newline pressed by the user will get read in as the value to the first `scanf`.  Put a blank space at the beginning of each `scanf` pattern to eat any newlines that may be in the buffer.
- When you're printing the result, you're printing `x` as the second operand instead of `y`.

When you apply the above, you should have this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x, y, result;
    char op;

    printf("****************\n");
    printf("A-----Add\n");
    printf("S-----Substract\n");
    printf("M-----MUltiply\n");
    printf("D-----Divide\n");
    printf("Q-----Quit\n");
    printf("****************\n");

    do {
        // these four lines go inside the loop to prompt again
        printf("Enter the operation:");
        scanf(" %c", &op);    // the space at the start eats the newline
        printf("Enter the two variables:");
        scanf(" %d %d", &x, &y);   // the space at the start eats the newline

        if (op == 'A')
            result = x + y;
        else if (op == 'S')
            result = x - y;
        else if (op == 'M')
            result = x*y;
        else if (op == 'D')
            result = x / y;
        else if (op == 'Q')
            break;
    //  compare op against each value individually
    } while (op != 'A' && op != 'Q' && op != 'M' && op != 'D' && op != 'S');

    printf("%d %c %d = %d\n", x, op, y, result);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while (op != 'A' && op != 'Q' && op !='M' && op !='D' && op !='S');
```